# How can I make a batch file or script file which will be able to auto login into any router with provided password

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

How can I make a bat file or script file which will be able to auto login into any router with provided password...
I tried a script code but this is not taking password and asking to enter in coming cmd window..
Please help either in this vb script or any other solution ..

```
Set cloner = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

cloner.run"cmd"

WScript.Sleep 500

cloner.SendKeys "telnet 0.0.0.0"

cloner.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 500

cloner.SendKeys "My password"

cloner.SendKeys ("{Enter}")

WScript.Sleep 5000
```

Comment: Think of it. Every freaking router has either it's own web interface, with it's own naming on input fields and such, some have no web interface at all, some are administered via telnet, others via SSH. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your question and add the tag **Vbscript**

As he said **Markus W Mahlberg** in the comment

> Every freaking router has either it's own web interface, with it's own
>   naming on input fields and such, some have no web interface at all,
>   some are administered via telnet, others via SSH.

So you can give a try at this vbscript and i hope that you have a chance; It will work for you ;)

**RebootMyRouter.vbs** I use it to reboot my router via **Telnet**

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyHote,MyLogin,MyPassword 
MyHote = "192.168.1.1" 'Change this line to your host
MyLogin = "admin"
MyPassword = "admin" 'Change this line with your password
Call Reboot_MyRouter(MyHote,MyLogin,MyPassword)
'******************************************************************************
Sub Reboot_MyRouter(MyHote,MyLogin,MyPassword)
Dim ws,Command,StrCommand,Execution
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    Command = "Telnet " & MyHote
    StrCommand = "cmd /c color 9B & mode con cols=65 lines=10 & "& Command &""
    Execution = ws.run(StrCommand,1,False)
    wscript.sleep 500
    ws.AppActivate Command
    ws.sendkeys MyLogin
    ws.sendkeys "{enter}"
    wscript.sleep 1000
    ws.sendkeys MyPassword
    ws.sendkeys "{enter}"
End Sub
'******************************************************************************
```